# Code koans for C?

Tags: c, clojure, tdd, lisp

Is there a Code Koans Set for C or Lisp?
I've found Koans in this languages, but no one in C or Lisp:

- Ruby: http://rubykoans.com/
- JavaScript: https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/javascript-koans
- Clojure: https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans
- Scala: https://github.com/rubbish/scala-koans

Answer (score 6):

May the following apocryphal stories and parables from the heyday of UNIX, C and LISP bring you some fun and enlightenment.

[AI koans](http://catb.org/jargon/html/koans.html)

[Rootless root](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/unix-koans/)

Answer (score 4):

They exist for Lisp now but not yet for C. There are C++ Koans though:

[Lisp Koans](http://github.com/search?q=koans+language%3Alisp&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

[C++ Koans](http://github.com/search?q=koans%20language%3ac%2b%2b&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)